# Binary Formatter not really Working (Unity, C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, binary

This code should make a File where the UUID cant be read by normal people locking in the file but  this is the output :

```
    ÿÿÿÿ          $45b7f364-99ce-4f4a-b592-21d3a40ae79a
```

and you can see the full UUID : 45b7f364-99ce-4f4a-b592-21d3a40ae79a

What is the problem or am i understanding the Binary Formatter wrong?

```
    private void Start()
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + @"\Saves\Local\PlayerInfo\"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.persistentDataPath + @"\Saves\Local\PlayerInfo\");
        }

        print(playerUUID());
    }

    public string playerUUID()
    {
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + @"\Saves\Local\PlayerInfo\" + "PlayerInfo.data";
        string pathbackup = Application.persistentDataPath + @"\Saves\Local\PlayerInfo\" + "PlayerInfo.data.backup";
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            try
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

                FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

                print("UUID Found");

                return formatter.Deserialize(stream) as string;
            }
            catch
            {
                print("UUID Damaged! Creating new");

                File.Copy(path, pathbackup);

                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

                string newUUID = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                formatter.Serialize(stream, newUUID);
                stream.Close();

                return newUUID;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print("UUID not found! Creating new");

            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

            string newUUID = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            formatter.Serialize(stream, newUUID);
            stream.Close();

            return newUUID;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just write ToString() into file. Binary whatever used not for readability, but to minimize resource consumption. Also, you leaking file handles and not flushing streams, wrap all streams into *using* clauses.

Comment: You want encryption and perhaps authentication if you want to verify the file isn't modified. BinaryFormatter won't hide your data, and since strings are serialized as is, they're readable by text editor.

Comment: Honestly, BinaryFormatter should basically never be used. If you want it loosely obfuscated, ToByteArray() gives you bytes; just write those to the file (and use the constructor that takes the same, obviously)

Comment: Why are you converting to a string?  Binary formatting is meant for binary data.  Conversion to string will lead to errors.  You coulld make the output of the binary formater a MemoryStream.  The use convert to a base64 string which should work.

Comment: In general [**Don't use `BinaryFormatter` anymore**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide) at all! Why not simply read/write the **string** itself? `File.WriteAllText`/`File.ReadAllText` -> done